# Android: Can I set another video player to be used by <video> tag?

Tags: android, html5-video

I want to have a HTML5 app with an embedded video player.

Normally I would simply use the `<video>` tag where appropriate. But I need to tell android to use a different player than the default one used for this tag. Is there a way to archive that?

Can I for example make it use an self compiled ExoPlayer? Or am I stuck with whatever is hidden behind the `<video>` tag?

Comment: I would like to provide our own player, most likely based on exoplayer that will be part of the APK we deliver. The HTML based app should have an inline video (not fullscreen) that uses this own player instead whatever is used now if I specify the video tag

Comment: Only from within my own app.

Comment: Well to clarify. We will use this HTML5 app on other platforms as well. Hence we won't go native. But here I am searching solely for a solution for our Android APP.

Answer (score 1):

Your webview can communicate with your Java/Kotlin code via [addJavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Start by creating a class that you will later set as the `WebView`'s JavaScript interface. Annotate the method(s) you want to expose to JavaScript with `@JavascriptInterface`. You can also add arguments to these method(s):

```
class MyJsInterface() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun onShowNativePlayer() {
        // Add your logic to show the native player instead of the HTML5.
    }
}
```

Create an instance of the above class and pass it to your `WebView`:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(MyJsInterface(), "android_js_interface")
```

And, finally, this is how you can trigger the exposed Java/Kotlin method(s) from your JavaScript code:

```
// This value should match the second argument that you passed in addJavascriptInterface. 
var ANDROID_JS_INTERFACE = "android_js_interface"
...
// Call your Java/Kotlin method.
window[ANDROID_JS_INTERFACE].onShowNativePlayer()
```

**Bonus:**

You can also achieve the reverse (ie. call JavaScript methods from your Java/Kotlin code):

```
myWebView.evaluateJavascript("myJsFunc()", null)
```

Where `myJsFunc()` is a function you defined in your JavaScript code:

```
// You can also pass arguments.
window.myJsFunc = function() {
    // Do something here.
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this means I have to use a native fragment and can't embed it into the view via <video> tag, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Unfortunately, what you described is not possible.

Comment: Ok, unless someone else comes around the corner proving you wrong, you'll get the bounty. At least I got a two way communication example from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way would be to bundle my own compiled browser that has the video player replaced. But this would be over the top here.

If nothing else turns up, I will opt for using a video fragment in the background with a transparent HTML5 App in front as a compromise.